# No puedo Agregar una pagina dinamica en jspdf

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

te recuerdo que yo el id o el HtmlElement se lo paso por parámetro, no tengo instalado jquery en mi proyecto ni tampoco tengo el html en el mismo lugar que el code js, asi que es la única manera, pasárselo a la función general y llamarlo en el momento de html2canvas. lo unico que me esta faltando es que no puedo usar el $ para señalar el id, por lo tanto lo mando de otra manera pero me da error en el parametro

`downloadPDF(id: any){
  var reporte = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(id); 
  html2canvas((reporte)[0],{allowTaint:true}).then((canvas) => {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var imgWidth = 210;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;

      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "a4");
      var position = 0;

      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+10);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
          position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
          doc.addPage();
          doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+10);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
    doc.save("Dashboard.pdf");
    });
}`

***EDITADO:***

no se me dio jaja, te mando como lo tengo, es muy complicado el asunto, estoy hace bastante ya intentando solucionarlo y la verdad que no se me da jajaj

[image: me faltan bastantes cosas ahi debajo donde corta el pdf]

Comment: Edita la pregunta, mayúsculas == gritar. Gracias. Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero realizar el recorrido, ver cómo formular preguntas y aquí una lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: es la primera vez que hago una pregunta, y la idea no es "gritar" es darle énfasis a las cosas que estoy colocando en mayúscula, pero gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: en ese caso, puedes usar negritas. Lo que te digo, es regla universal de los foros que hay en la red. Saludos.

Comment: Puedes editar un poco mas, y mostrar el error?

Comment: Ya se cual es tu problema: tomas document.getElementById, lo que busca un elemento con id, no un array de elementos con classe, como en mi ejemplo. Entonces, quita el [0] en este linea: `html2canvas((reporte)[0],{allowTaint:true}).then((canvas) => {` y ya, estas mas cerquita!

Comment: ahi te edite para que veas como me da el pdf, siempre me pasa lo mismo, o me agrega una hoja y me muestra un texto mas y no termina de mostrar todo lo que necesito, es muy dificil jajaj laverdad que me esta matando

Answer (score 0):

Parece que ya estás cerca de solución. Este código se encuentra en varias preguntas en StackOverflow en inglés. Te refiero con una pregunta de allí y sua respuesta y ademas un cierto comentario.

[1] tiene una comentario, que si no se encuentra el contexto `window.onePageCanvas` puedes alterar el código así:

```
 var onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

Así no importa si existe un contexto o no, tu solo creas un `var` nuevo.

Encuentro:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069124/how-to-save-a-image-in-multiple-pages-of-pdf-using-jspdf

**Editando:**

Yo hice un ejemplo que funciona live, cuando lo copias:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

  function test() {
    html2canvas($('.foo')[0],{allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var imgWidth = 210;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;

      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "a4");
      var position = 0;

      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+10);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
          position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
          doc.addPage();
          doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+10);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
    doc.save("Dashboard.pdf");
    });
  }
</script>
<style>
    table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        font: 64px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body> 
   <div id="container-fluid" class="foo">
    <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="20%">
                <col width="20%">
                    <col width="20%">
                        <col width="20%">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr class='warning'>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Chinna</td>
                <td>1,363,480,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>19.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>1,241,900,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>17.4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano0</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano1</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano2</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>País lejano</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <button onclick="javascript:test()">ping</button>
</body>
```

Con cierto nivel de zoom (90% en mi pantalla) lo gambia pagina casi suavemente:

[image: nivel de zoom cierto]

Encontre el ejemplo de [aqui](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/650). Lo que me gusta en este enquentro es, que esto es ejemplo que funciona, y por lo menos en mi caso, el gambio de pagina no toma parte fuera del texto(, aunque no esta perfecto tampoco, lo siento.)

Intente unos cinco soluciones, esto fue lo unico que me daba resultados buenas. La base de solucion que embezamos utilizar, no esta bien, o algo en versiones ha cambiado y ya no sirve por nada. Yo tenia en mi pantalla lo mismo error que tu.

Comment: Sii! lo vi a ese comentario, Muchas gracias por darme una mano, lo que me sucede con ese " var" es que si lo coloco, me da error en los parametros de las medidas que le paso, es como que no entiende esos numeros que le doy como parametro, fijate que en la funcion, debajo del onepagecanvas esta el 900 y el 980 como parametro, bueno eso me da error. si tenes idea me darias una mano gigante

Comment: En este ejemplo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220678/setattribute-width-for-canvas-as-percentage-value) se da los numeros entre comillas.. como "900" y "980".

Comment: sisi! pude de esa manera pero me sigue generando el pdf sin las hojas que necesito, es como que me achica el tamaño de la letra y todo pero de todas maneras me corta el texto y no me sigue generando el pdf con el tamaño y las paginas necesarias, pero seguiré buscando la solución

Comment: Todavia te da un error? Lo puedas mostrarme, cual error es y de que linea de codigo?

Comment: No me da error, si no que no me funciona, me dejo de dar error, el code ejecuta, pero no hace lo que necesito, me sigue cortando el pdf, me genera solo dos hojas y minimo el informe que tengo necesita 3, de todas maneras, tengo para hacer muchos informes, por ahi alguno tengo de 50 hojas y necesito que se generen solas esas 50 hojas y con su texto correpondiente, que se extienda tanto como lo necesita el code.

Comment: esa funcion no me estaria solucionando el problema, pero me dejo de dar error con tu ayuda

Comment: a ver, un poco tiempo de busca, intentos varios y aqui tiene! Hice un ejemplo completo de solucion mejor que podia encontrar.

Comment: excelente ese ejemplo, voy a editar mi pregunta, asi te actualizo con lo que tengo hasta ahora, copie exactamente el mismo ejemplo, pero como no uso jquery, y no tengo el html dentro del componente, lo que hago es pasar el id por parametro, y estoy intentando hacer que le parametro sea mi id para probar tu solucion, desde ya muchas gracias por todo sos un genio, gracias por el tiempo etc, te edito la pregunta principal para que veas lo que te digo.